# Allow,Deny from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a small problem trying to add the option Allow,Deny in my .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.10.100
allow from 192.168.10.200
</Limit>

Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I cannot get in in the folder where is this .htaccess, the ip address is correct, if i keep only

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.10.100
allow from 192.168.10.200
</Limit>
```

I can get in to the folder. but if i put together is not working anymore.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, if this block alone works, the problem is obviously in the rest of your .htaccess and has nothing to do with ALLOW/DENY. Or did i misread the second part of your post?